Tough version of unmet dependencies / broken packages in Debian - how to repair system?
After trying to install steam with nala (alternative to apt) some 70 packages were broken and I found no way to fix it nor can I update/install/remove packages!
Here is what I did:

"# nala install steam" got output:
Notice: Selecting steam:i386
Instead of virtual package steam
steam:i386 has been unmarked.
Try --no-fix-broken if you're sure they can be installed.

So I tried: "# nala install steam --no-fix-broken" which installed about 30 packages incl. libraries like e.g.
liblzma5:i386                                 5.2.5-2.1~deb11u1                                                                 176 KB
...
libelf1:i386                                  0.183-1                                                                           171 KB
...
libvulkan1:i386                               1.3.216.0-1~mx21ahs+1                                                             129 KB
...
libxfixes3:i386                               1:6.0.0-1~mx21ahs+1                                                                23 KB
...
steam:i386                                    1.0.0.68-1                                                                        1.6 MB


but also removed the following:
Package:                                      Version:                                                                           Size:
libelf1                                       0.187-1~bpo11+1                                                                   1.1 MB
liblzma5                                      5.4.1-0.2~mx21+1                                                                  345 KB
libvulkan1                                    1.3.224.0-1mx21+1                                                                 546 KB
libxfixes3                                    1:6.0.0-1~mx21+1                                                                   61 KB
...and ended with error:
" Error: Installation has failed.
If you'd like to file a bug report please include '/var/log/nala/dpkg-debug.log'
Error: libelf1:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
rpm depends on libelf1 (>= 0.131).
...... " (list of dependency errors caused by removed packages)...

Afterwards in Synaptic 70 packages were broken and any attempt to reinstall or remove or purge or upgrade or install any (broken or working or new) package returns in a list of (always same) ~300 packages that have to be removed (and cannot be unselected) !!!: e.g. accountservice, .... alsa-utils, .... apt, ..... aptitude, ...bluetooth, ... cmake, ...cups, ... dpkg, ... firefox, .... flatpak, .... ghostscript, ....gimp, ... gufw, ... kde-plasma-desktop, ....konsole, ...nvidia-driver, .... pulsaudio,.... policykit-1, ..... python3,.....qt5ct,........rsyslog, ....samba, ....sddm....vulkantools, ........xorg,.....xterm,.....So basically it would remove all essential system apps that would totally break the system when removed, which I didn't do of course!

"sudo apt upgrade" outputs list of all (70) unmet dependencies and following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
chromium : Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not installed
debugedit : Depends: libelf1 (>= 0.144) but it is not installed
dpkg : PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not installed
dwz : Depends: libelf1 (>= 0.131) but it is not installed
elinks : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installed
firefox : Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not installed
....
gimp : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installed
Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not installed
gnome-disk-utility : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installed
grub-common : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installed
....
xz-utils : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

"sudo apt --fix-broken install" outputs same unmet dependencies list as 4. above and
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies


...but there are no held packages! "sudo apt-mark showhold" outputs nothing!

installing or removing with aptitude also doesn't work: e.g. "sudo aptitude remove brave-browser" outputs:

The following packages will be REMOVED:
brave-browser
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 376 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dpkg : PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
linux-kbuild-5.10 : Depends: libelf1 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
linux-kbuild-5.16 : Depends: libelf1 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
libxenmisc4.14 : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not going to be installed
...
libkf5archive5 : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
open: 7411; closed: 66534; defer: 106; conflict: 145                                                          oNo solution found within the allotted time.  Try harder? [Y/n] y
Resolving dependencies...
open: 15230; closed: 99054; defer: 126; conflict: 185                                                         oNo solution found within the allotted time.  Try harder? [Y/n] y
Resolving dependencies...
open: 24074; closed: 125906; defer: 132; conflict: 192                                                        oNo solution found within the allotted time.  Try harder? [Y/n] n
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
brave-browser
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 376 MB will be freed.
aptitude failed to find a solution to these dependencies.  You can solve them yourself by hand or type 'n' to quit.

forced removal worked with e.g. "sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq brave-browser", but i cant re-install it - see 3. above!

I am using following Debian GNU 6.1. with Linux 11 (bullseye) with KDE Plasma 5.20 and the following repos, which I didn't change:


deb http://mirror.i3d.net/debian/ bullseye-updates non-free contrib main
deb http://mirror.i3d.net/debian/ bullseye non-free contrib main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security non-free contrib main
deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ bullseye main
deb http://mirror.i3d.net/debian/ bullseye-updates non-free contrib main
deb https://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/mxlinux/mx/repo/ bullseye non-free main
deb https://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/mxlinux/mx/repo/ bullseye ahs
Since dpkg itself is broken it looks like this is the main issue: it (pre)depends on liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0), but ver. 5.2.5-2.1~deb11u1 is installed (see above!).
Manually instaling liblzma5_5.4.1-0.2_amd64.deb (or again dpkg) is also not working:
"sudo dpkg -i liblzma5_5.4.1-0.2_amd64.deb" outputs:
dpkg-deb: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5: version `XZ_5.4' not found (required by dpkg-deb)
dpkg: error processing archive liblzma5_5.4.1-0.2_amd64.deb (--install):
dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
liblzma5_5.4.1-0.2_amd64.deb
.. so it looks liblzma5 (>= 5.4.0) is needed (for dpkg) to install liblzma5 vers. 5.4. itself ! A vicious circle!
So I have manually extracted the library file from the .deb package and copied it into the library directory incl. symlinking:
"sudo cp liblzma.so.5.4.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
"sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.4.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5"
..and deleted / renamed the old file (liblzma.so.5.2.5)
but then it got even worse: trying to run any more complex programs just as synaptic,  brave-browser, kwrite or apt etc. outputs e.g.:
synaptic: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5) synaptic: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5)
and I have read that Installing GLIBC (GNU C Library) manually is a complex and potentially risky process and it's generally not recommended as it can lead to system instability.
So here I gave up (changed  liblzma5 ver. 5.4. back to ver. 5.2.5 by copying and symliking the other file as described abovve.
I hope someone can help me, since I don't want to re-install the whole system and actually want to know how to solve this and pot. future issues with dependencies.

There are multiple steps to fixing broken packages, as outlined at NinjaOne.com. Run the following, in sequence:

sudo apt-get check
This lists problematic packages.

sudo apt-mark showhold
This shows packages that cannot be installed yet due to unresolved issues.

sudo apt search <package_name> for each package from 2.
This lists information on those packages, such as versions and dependencies.

sudo apt list -a <package_name> for each such package.
This finds versions that are in all repositories.

Perform sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade to get the low-hanging fruit.

Install dependencies from 3. using `sudo apt install <dependency_name> for each item.

Perform sudo apts install –fix-broken to fix packages that are not held.


Frankly, your question shows you've made a great many changes. Though you want to fix all the 70-or-so issues mentioned piecemeal, it might be easier to do one of the following.

Restore the system from the last drive image made, which you should have done at the beginning. This is a quick, easy, reliable fix, likely taking less than a half-hour to complete, with no need for supervision.

If you do not have a drive image,

Make a full image now.
Remove all partitions and reinstall the OS.
Restore data and packages from the image to get a stable system.


In either case, try reinstalling Steam, perhaps avoiding nala.



I'm not sure aptis aware of changes made by the alternative nala the OP. It could be, it should be, but I don't know.

@ChanganAuto, agreed -- even another reason to abandon piecemeal fix.

Thanks "DrMoishe Pippik" for your comment, I appreciate it.
However I already tried these standard solutions and the problems lie deeper in the system (e.g. dpkg itself is broken - and therefore apt, synaptic etc also produce errors, see above!) and of course I could re-install, but I want to solve this without.

It sounds like the root issue is all that brokenness in your system, your current issue is a symptom, not a cause, and so you should be focusing on fixing all that other broken stuff first.


Reboot from a live USB (same system (here: Linux mx21))
Mount the compromised system (partition) (e.g. on /mnt/fx-ed-up-system)
Copy the installed files of the DPK package (can be seen e.g. in synaptic - installed files) and the 4 originally (falsely, forced) removed packages (here: libelf1,liblzma5, libvulkan1, libxfixes3, see above!) to the mounted, compromised system in the same directory structure - see as an example the first (of some 100) files of dpkg package (output from synaptic) - but you have to do that for all (critical) packages and files of course:

/etc
/etc/alternatives
/etc/alternatives/README
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/dpkg
/etc/dpkg
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/alternatives
/etc/logrotate.d/dpkg
/sbin
/sbin/start-stop-daemon
....
which I copied (as root) from the root of the live system to the root of the mounted one with "--parents" to preserve the directory structure, which will overwrite existing (wrong/too old or new (lib) files and copy missing ones; for some packages "-R" must be added if cp errors occur):
"cp --parents /etc/alternatives/README /etc/cron.daily/dpkg /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d /etc/logrotate.d/alternatives /etc/logrotate.d/dpkg /sbin/start-stop-daemon /mnt/fx-ed-up-system/"

Reboot the compromised system and it immediately recognized no errors in certain (working) packages (e.g. dolphin or a other apps crashed/produced sometimes errors and complained about missing / wrong libs etc.) although synaptic still showed the 70 broken packages and i still couldn't install/remove/upgrade/fix etc. any packages (without the required removal of some 300 (working) packages (see above!)). So the system seemed to work fine although the package management (synaptic) didn't.

Remove a broken package with aptitude (here: brave-browser) which also showed me the 70 unmet dependencies but this time immediately showed a solution by removing xz-utils (5.4.) and installing the 4 originally (falsely, forced) removed packages (here: libelf1,liblzma5, libvulkan1, libxfixes3) and also xz-utils:i386  as well as suggested to downgrade dpkg . After accepting it, you should receive no errors, reinstall the brave-browser with aptitude and WHOOOOOOPS: after restarting synaptic all 60 broken packages where working again (not shown as broken, but installed)


In short: Manually copy all critical (and previously removed) package files from a live system to the compromised system and using aptitude to remove and reinstall one package (maybe that was a coincidence, but synaptic didn't work at the first try) (I also think it has to be from the live system of your same distro version, since e.g. downloading the exact same .deb-package from the debian site (with exact same version) and copying the files didn't work!)

i dunno which idiot downgraded this, but this is actually the WORKING SOLUTION for the above problem which i found myself !!!
